# How do i know if a Jcheckbox is checked?in GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, checkbox, jgrasp

can you tell me in details how do i know if a jcheckbox is checked or not? method isSelected  didn't work with me it gives me an exception while running

```
{
 Sandwich = new JButton("Tall");
         contentPane.add(Tall);
         Sandwitch.setBounds(350, 110, 90,40);   //in main
         Sandwitch.addActionListener(this);

}
.....

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
JButton clickedButton = (JButton) event.getSource();

        String  buttonText = clickedButton.getText();
..........
if(clickedButton.getText()=="Sandwitch"){
        if(Ketchup.getState()&&!Garlic.getState()){//

       itm=new Item(""+m+clickedButton.getText(),3.0);
        xyz.addItem(itm);
       textArea.append(" "+clickedButton.getText()+",");
        textArea.append(" "+itm.getPrice()+"\n");}

          else if(!Ketchup.isSelected()&&Garlic.isSelected()){//

....................
}
```

it gives a very long exception while running

can you please help me with this problem?

Comment: what is the Exception??

Comment: what does the exception say....null pointer ???

Comment: What do u meant by  **very long exception** ?

Comment: Nobody can help you without knowing the exception you are getting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).  As to the 'very long' exception. Trim the bulk of it that references JSE classes out.  Add the rest as an edit.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `==` to compare Strings!

```
if (clickedButton.getText()=="Sandwitch"){}
```

Use `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase()`

```
if ("Sandwich".equalsIgnoreCase(clickedButton.getText()){
    // do something
}
```

Comment: -1, this won't remove OP's exception.

Comment: This didn't help me getting rid of the exception.

Comment: @user3049389 you never posted your exception. How are we supposed to know what the exception is? Consider posting an [SCCEE](http://sccee.org) for more help.

Comment: You have posted the same question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20289002/how-do-i-know-if-a-jcheckbox-is-checkedwith-gui   The null pointer could be due to some object (may be the checkbox itself) has not been initiated...